# Sora R3000 brifters with the M4000 rear derailleur

Tags: shifter, compatibility

Is the pull ratio still the same ? I can only find info on the older gen sora shifters not the most updated ones..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rear derailleur cable pull ratio, unlike the front one, is still the same. You can use any (7-)8-9 speed RD.

Comment: alright thanks ! :)